# Parametrized unit tests in Swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing, parameterized-unit-test

Is there any way to use parameterized unit tests, similar to what you can achieve in .Net using [NUnit](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCase-Attribute) framework.

```
[TestCase(12, 3, 4)]
[TestCase(12, 2, 6)]
[TestCase(12, 4, 3)]
public void DivideTest(int expectedResult, int a, int b)
{
  Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, a / b);
}
```

Using this kind of tests (vs non-parameterized ones) can give you bigger back for buck by allowing you to avoid writing series of almost identical unit tests differing only by parameter values.

I am looking for either XCTest-based solution or some other means to achieve it. Optimal solution should report each test case (parameter set) as a separate unit test in Xcode, so is it clear whether all or only some of the tests cases failed.

Comment: You can extract part of the test method into a helper method. If you can read ObjC, this might help:http://qualitycoding.org/refactoring-tests/

Comment: Sadly, we're left to hack workarounds because XCTest *still* doesn't have parameterized tests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to handle parameterized testing is to use [`XCTContext.runActivity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/activities_and_attachments/grouping_tests_into_substeps_with_activities). This allows to create a new activity with some name that will help you identify exactly which of the iterations failed. So for your division scenario:

```swift
func testDivision() {
    let testCases = [
        (a: 12, b: 3, result: 4),
        (a: 12, b: 2, result: 6),
        (a: 12, b: 6, result: 1),
        (a: 12, b: 4, result: 3),
    ]
    for (a, b, result) in testCases {
        XCTContext.runActivity(named: "Testing dividing \(a) by \(b) to get result \(result)") { activity in
            XCTAssertEqual(result, a/b)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that after running the above test, case no. 1, 2 and 4 will succeed while case no. 3 will fail. You can view exactly which test activity failed and which of the assertions caused faiure in test report:

[image: Test activity with success and failure cases]

Answer (score 16):

The best way to use parametrized is using the XCTestCase subclass's property `defaultTestSuite`. A clear example with division is the following:

```
import XCTest

class ParameterizedExampleTests: XCTestCase {
    
    //properties to save the test cases
    private var array: [Float]? = nil
    private var expectedResult: Float? = nil
    
    // This makes the magic: defaultTestSuite has the set of all the test methods in the current runtime
    // so here we will create objects of ParameterizedExampleTests to call all the class' tests methodos
    // with differents values to test
    override open class var defaultTestSuite: XCTestSuite {
        let testSuite = XCTestSuite(name: NSStringFromClass(self))
        addTestsWithArray([12, 3], expectedResult: 4, toTestSuite: testSuite)
        addTestsWithArray([12, 2], expectedResult: 6, toTestSuite: testSuite)
        addTestsWithArray([12, 4], expectedResult: 3, toTestSuite: testSuite)
        return testSuite
    }
    
    // This is just to create the new ParameterizedExampleTests instance to add it into testSuite
    private class func addTestsWithArray(_ array: [Float], expectedResult: Float, toTestSuite testSuite: XCTestSuite) {
        testInvocations.forEach { invocation in
            let testCase = ParameterizedExampleTests(invocation: invocation)
            testCase.array = array
            testCase.expectedResult = expectedResult
            testSuite.addTest(testCase)
        }
    }

    // Normally this function is into production code (e.g. class, struct, etc).
    func division(a: Float, b: Float) -> Float {
        return a/b
    }
    
    func testDivision() {
        XCTAssertEqual(self.expectedResult, division(a: array?[0] ?? 0, b: array?[1] ?? 0))
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the tests of the suite only show up as a single test the Xcode test navigator. Is there a work around for that?

Comment: @tcurdt this is actually one single test running but validated several times so this should be shown as one test but with several invocations, it's to avoid generate unnecessary additional code coverage

Comment: Sure - but not being able to drill down to the invocation results greatly reduces the usefulness of this approach.

Answer (score 12):

You function parameters are all over the place. I'm not sure if your function is doing multiplication or division. But here's one way you can do multiple test cases in a single test method.

Given this function:

```
func multiply(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    return a * b
}
```

You can have multiple test cases on it:

```
class MyTest: XCTestCase {
    func testMultiply() {
        let cases = [(4,3,12), (2,4,8), (3,5,10), (4,6,20)]
        cases.forEach {
            XCTAssertEqual(multiply($0, $1), $2)
        }
    }
}
```

The last two would fail and Xcode will tell you about them.

Comment: A major downside of this, is that execution will stop when the first case fails. Where are paramterized tests continue, each case is treated as a seperate test in reports, which makes it much easier to pinpoint which exact combination has failed.

Comment: Please don't ever use `forEach`. It's incredibly ugly; just use a for loop.

Comment: @PeterSchorn Execution of the test cases: yes. Not execution of that specific test. If that is no longer the case, the behaviour might have been changed over time. Also; don't state your personal opinion of code style as law; nobody likes a bitter person.

Comment: When you say "that specific test" are you referring to a test method? Currently, execution will never stop when an XC assertion fails, unless you set `continueAfterFailure` to false, in which case the execution of the current test method will stop when a failure occurs.

Answer (score 4):

I rather like [@DariusV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6455357/dariusv)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50090681/3799856). However, it doesn't handle well when I the developer execute the test method directly from Xcode's sidebar. That's a dealbreaker for me.

What I wound up doing I think is rather slick.

I declare a `Dictionary` of `testValues` (probs need a better name for that) as an instance computed property of my `XCTestCase` subclass. Then, I define a `Dictionary` literal of inputs keying expected outputs. My example tests a function that acts on `Int`, so I define `testValues` like so:

```
static var testRange: ClosedRange<Int> { 0...100 }

var testValues: [Int: Int] {
    let range = Self.testRange
    return [
        // Lower extreme
        Int.min: range.lowerBound,

        // Lower bound
        range.lowerBound - 1: range.lowerBound,
        range.lowerBound    : range.lowerBound,
        range.lowerBound + 1: range.lowerBound + 1,

        // Middle
        25: 25,
        50: 50,
        75: 75,

        // Upper bound
        range.upperBound - 1: range.upperBound - 1,
        range.upperBound    : range.upperBound,
        range.upperBound + 1: range.upperBound,

        // Upper extreme
        Int.max: range.upperBound
    ]
}
```

Here, I very easily declare my edge and boundary cases. A more semantic way of accomplishing the same might be to use an array of tuples, but Swift's dictionary literal syntax is thin enough, and I know what this does.

Now, in my test method, I have a simple `for` loop.

```
/// The property wrapper I'm testing. This could be anything, but this works for example.
@Clamped(testRange) var number = 50

func testClamping() {
    let initial = number

    for (input, expected) in testValues {
        // Call the code I'm testing. (Computed properties act on assignment)
        number = input
        XCTAssertEqual(number, expected, "{number = \(input)}: `number` should be \(expected)")

        // Reset after each iteration.
        number = initial
    }
}
```

Now to run for each parameter, I simply invoke XCTests in any of Xcode's normal ways, or any other way that works with Linux (I assume). No need to run *every* test class to get this one's parameterizedness.

Isn't that pretty? I just covered every boundary value and equivalence class in only a few lines of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code!

As for identifying failing cases, each invocation runs through an `XCTAssert` function, which as per Xcode's convention will only throw a message at you if there's something wrong that you need to think about. These show up in the sidebar, but similar messages tend to blend together. My message string here identifies the failing input and its resulting output, fixing the blending-togetherness, and making my testing flow a sane piece of cherry apple pie. (You may format yours any way you like, bumpkin! Whatever blesses your sanity.)

Delicious.

### TL;DR

An adaptation of [@Code Different](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538939/code-different)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35447375/3799856): Use a dictionary of inputs and outputs, and run with a `for` loop.

Comment: Why do you need to take one extra obj for maintaining the current index when you can get index simply by enumerated on loop?

Comment: @nikhilnangia I... don't maintain the current index. I'm not sure what you mean; the loop gives me the current key and value in the dictionary.  I call my code using the key for the input and comparing the output with the value, which is the expected output. The `initial` value is set before the loop so that I can reset the state of my unit under test.  I don't see any index variable here.

Comment: Why is `testRange` a computed property? It's completely unnecessary. Just use a stored property. Also `testValues` doesn't need to be a computed property either. Both properties always return the same value.

Comment: @PeterSchorn You're right. `static let` should work just fine for this.

Comment: @SeizeTheDay Glad I could help improve your code. Also, you should avoid using instance properties in your test classes whenever possible. Believe it or not, XCTest actually creates a separate instance of your test class for each test method. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48562936/12394554. Therefore, you should use static/class properties instead.

Answer (score 3):

[@Code Different](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538939/code-different)'s answer is legit. Here's other two options, or rather **workarounds**:

### Property Based Testing

You could use a tool like [Fox](https://github.com/jeffh/Fox) to perform *generative testing*, where the test framework will generate many input sets for the behaviour you want to test and run them for you.

More on this approach:

- http://www.pivotaltracker.com/community/tracker-blog/generative-testing
- http://blog.jessitron.com/2013/04/property-based-testing-what-is-it.html

### BDD Shared Examples

If you like the [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) style and are using a test framework that supports them, you could use **shared examples**.

Using [Quick](https://github.com/Quick/Quick) it would look like:

```
class MultiplySharedExamplesConfiguration: QuickConfiguration {
  override class func configure(configuration: Configuration) {
    sharedExamples("something edible") { (sharedExampleContext: SharedExampleContext) in
      it("multiplies two numbers") {
        let a = sharedExampleContext()["a"]
        let b = sharedExampleContext()["b"]
        let expectedResult = sharedExampleContext()["b"]

        expect(multiply(a, b)) == expectedResult
      }
    }
  }
}

class MultiplicationSpec: QuickSpec {
  override func spec() {
    itBehavesLike("it multiplies two numbers") { ["a": 2, "b": 3, "result": 6] }
    itBehavesLike("it multiplies two numbers") { ["a": 2, "b": 4, "result": 8] }
    itBehavesLike("it multiplies two numbers") { ["a": 3, "b": 3, "result": 9] }
  }
}
```

To be honest this option is: 1) a lot of work, 2) a misuse of the shared example technique, as you are not using them to test behaviour shared by multiple classes but rather to parametrise the test. But as I said at the start, this is a more of a workaround.

Comment: I like the general idea of generative testing. Perhaps it can be used in conjunction with ObjC runtime to achieve test parametrisation. Definitively a good source of inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

With the advent of Swift Macros, you can do exactly what you want in pure Swift. My colleague and I have developed a neat Swift Macro for parameterized XCTest. With this, you can simply use:

```
@Parametrize(input: [(3, 4), (2, 6), (4, 3)], output: [12, 12, 12])
func testDivide(input numbers: (Int, Int), output result: Int) {
  XCTAssertEqual(numbers.0 / numbers.1, result)
}
```

The macro will create a copy of your method for a given parameter set.
Check it out here: https://github.com/PGSSoft/XCTestParametrizedMacro

Answer (score 1):

The asserts all seem to `throw`, so perhaps something like this will work for you:

```
typealias Division = (dividend: Int, divisor: Int, quotient: Int)

func testDivisions() {
    XCTAssertNoThrow(try divisionTest((12, 3, 4)))
    XCTAssertNoThrow(try divisionTest((12, 2, 6)))
    XCTAssertNoThrow(try divisionTest((12, 4, 3)))
}

private func divisionTest(_ division: Division) throws {
    XCTAssertEqual(division.dividend / division.divisor, division.quotient)
}
```

If one fails, the entire function will fail. If more granularity is required, every case can be split up into an individual function.

Answer (score 1):

We found that this solution [How to Dynamically add XCTestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142213/how-to-dynamically-add-xctestcase/55204082) offers us the flexibility we need. Being able to dynamically add tests, pass arguments to tests, and display the dynamic test names in the test report.

Another option is to checkout XCTestPlan in XCode.  [There's an informative video from WWDC about it.](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/413/)